# Ayuda con bs-datepicker de AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Me gustaría saber si se puede modificar la directiva `ds-datepicker` de AngularJS para mostrar solo los meses y los años

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Por favor brinda más detalles de tu problema, provee información para entender qué estás haciendo, en dónde te has detenido y qué es lo que debes lograr. Si no muestras interés y esfuerzo en tu pregunta, nadie en este sitio demostrará esfuerzo ni interés en responderla.

Answer (score 2):

Basándome en esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25386991/angularjs-bootstrap-datepicker-format-set-to-mm-yyyy-yet-allows-users-to-e), creo que buscas es esto:

```
element.datepicker({
                    format: "mm-yyyy", //Seteas el formato
                    minViewMode: "months", // Que campos mostraras al desplegar el datepick
                    startDate: "01-1000",
                    endDate: "12-9999",                        
                    orientation: "top left",
                    autoclose: true,
                    onSelect: function (date) {
                        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(date);
                        scope.$apply();
                    }
                });
```

Con `format: "mm-yyyy"` le das el formato deseado que vas a mostrar en este caso Mes/Año y con `minViewMode: "months"` el campo que se monstrara al desplegar.

Comment: ¿Y el atributo `format` no será importante acá también?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Al final lo deje como lo coloque inicialmente, ya que me quede con la duda, esperemos que el dueño de la pregunta nos diga si le sirvió.

Comment: Bueno, la pregunta (vagamente redactada) dice *para mostrar **solo los meses y los años*** así que me parece que se debería usar `format` en este caso.